# How do you pass values from an html file into a c# file to be processed?

Tags: c#, html, get, cgi

I'm trying to pass in values from a html file into a c# file using "get" as my method. my c# code currently looks like this:

```
namespace animals
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var endpoint = new Uri("C:/localWebSite/cgi-zoo.html");
                var result = client.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my form submission line looks like this:

```
<form name="zooForm" action="C:\localWebSite\theZoo\animals.exe" method="get" onsubmit="return getAnimal();">
```

What I need to do is pass in 2 variables for use and it needs to be a string and an int, The c# code will then return the user to another page (from the c# code not another html) that displays a picture and some supporting text for the picture. From those data types the most important one is the int because I need to use it to determine what picture I am going to show back to the user and what text document I'm going to use to support that picture.

My problem is I'm having a hard time figuring out how exactly data gets passed from the html into the c# program and when it does eventually get passed how to separate it into the string and the integer.

Comment: `result` is a string. You need to extract the information from it ... By getting a subset by index, using a regular expression to find it, etc.

Comment: @Steve I don't think that's what he's asking...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think you need to be a little more specific. If I had to guess, you want this.

Html Page 1

```
@*some html*@
<form action="yourAction" method="get">
        <input type="number" name="numBer" />
        <input type="text" name="someString" />
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT FORM" />
    </form>
```

then the form will send to the action, here:

```
public IActionResult yourAction(string fooBar, int numBer)
    {
        //write in your logic here, like find the picture that matched 'numBer'

        //then, when you are ready, do below. I included the parameter because 
        //you might need it
        return RedirectToAction("theNextView", new { numBer = numBer });
    }
```

which will send the user to the next view.

although, maybe i totally misread this question. but thats how I interpret what you are asking. also, you should probably 'post' the data to the action, not 'get'